# i got this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php, mysql

please help me with this error
i could not find the solution. here's the code :

```
public function store_image($id) {
    $db = connection();
    $if ($db->connect_errno == 0) {
        $sql = "SELECT * from car where id='$id'";
        $res = $db->query($sql);
        while ($row = $db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $pic = $row['pic'];
        }
        header("content_type: image/jpg");
    }
}
```

the error says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'" on this line :

```
$sql = "SELECT * from car where id='$id'";
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

please change following line

```php
$if ($db->connect_errno == 0) {
```

to

```php
if ($db->connect_errno == 0) {
```

Look your have added extra `$` before `if` statement

Remove this `$` from `if` statement.